# Is there a way to detect whether an event was triggered using input devices or via script as in .onEvent()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way to detect whether an event was triggered using input devices or via script as in `.onEvent()`?

Comment: Did the originalEvent property help you or was there something else you were looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short story, no.

The only thing you can examine is the `event object` which is passed into a callback handler (the "event handler"). Like *typeof* suggested in his answer, there might be propertys which aren't set if the event was triggered by device (or vice versa), but then again it's 100% NOT reliable. Example:

```
$('someinputcontrol').trigger({
    type:          'keydown',
    originalEvent: true
});
```

You can add any property to the event object using this technique. So again, there is no reliable way to detect whether an event was fired due to device or script.

Comment: Interesting take on this. I would think it highly unlikely to encounter this... and if you're only working with your own code, you can ensure this will **never** happen by not passing the originalEvent property.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can inspect the event object passed to the event handler to see if it was an artificial event or not:

```
if(event.originalEvent) {
    ...
}
```

It seems like the event object will have a property called **originalEvent** if the event was triggered by input device rather than script.